# Illegal argument name - Arquillian with Cucumber

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, jboss-arquillian, cucumber-junit

I'm learning how to code a simple JUnit test with Arquillian framework and Cucumber jvm.

Code:

```
package br.com.cielo.batcha.test;

...

@RunWith(CukeSpace.class)
@Features("classpath:br/com/cielo/batcha/features/MSG_MANUTENCAO.feature")

public class ARunner {

@Deployment
public static JavaArchive  createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
            .addClass(BatchaApplication.class);
}


@Quando("^Sistema de teste estiver conectado ao Banco$")
public void sistema_de_teste_estiver_conectado_ao_Banco() throws Throwable {
    Assert.fail("Not yet implemented");
}

}
```

When I try to run this test above, I received this message:

```
Tests in error:
    ARunner.performInternalCucumberOperations >> IllegalArgument name
```

Any ideas how could I solve this problem? tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this part :

```
@Features("classpath:br/com/cielo/batcha/features/MSG_MANUTENCAO.feature")
```

To:

```
@Features("src/test/java/br/com/cielo/batcha/features/MSG_MANUTENCAO.feature")
```

Solved my problem.

Comment: Normally any non-java files reside below `src/test/resources`, thats why the `classpath:`-path didn't work.